# Form click function to check variable before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am using a `$.get` function to check the connection to the server before submitting the `ASP` login form. If the get function is successful and returns a true then the form should submit, otherwise if it fails and returns false, it should not.

I have tried many different configurations, but everything I've tried has either rendered the button inoperable, or only showing a true, and never a false!

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Enter" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" class="submitButton" />
```

**UPDATE** - The code below executes the get function correctly, but I have a feeling the problem lies within $('form').submit();

When true is returned the page refreshes like it sent the data, but the system does not log the user in. Why is this!?

```
submitButton.click(function () { // capitalize username on login

            var url = 'https://examplesite.com/';

            $.get(url).done(function () {

                if (usernameBox.val() === '') {
                    usernameBox.attr('placeholder', 'Username Required');
                    passwordBox.attr('placeholder', '');
                    usernameBox.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else if (passwordBox.length && passwordBox.val() === '') {
                    passwordBox.attr('placeholder', 'Password Required');
                    usernameBox.attr('placeholder', '');
                    passwordBox.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else if (passwordBox.length && passwordBox.val().length < 6) {
                    passwordBox.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    alert('Successful - Now logging in');
                    $('form').submit();
                }
            }).fail(function () {
                    alert('Failed - No Connection');
            });
            return false;
        });
    };
```

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: Are you checking internet connection?

Comment: Yes, I am checking Internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get` is an async function, so `online` is never set to what you think it is since the rest of the code is being processed before the call is complete. Move your logic into the `.done` part of it!

```
$.get(url).done(function () {
    online = true;

    if (online == true) {
        alert('Success');
        $('form').submit();
    }
    else if (online == false) {
        alert('Cannot Connect');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}).fail(function () {
    online = false;
});
```

Comment: OK, the form does not seem to submit when calling $('form') from with the if statement.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors at all, the page refreshes like it sent the data, but it's not logging the user in.

Comment: It is with status of 200